# What file does the python symlink point to

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I bought my mac about a year ago and somehow changed my python symlink so that when I run `python some_file.py`, python 3.4 is used to run the file instead of python 2.7. I now need to change it back, but I can't figure out what I did to change it in the first place! When I run:

```
import os
os.path.realpath("/usr/local/bin/python")
```

in the python terminal, the output is:

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7'
```

Does this not mean that my python symlink is pointing to my python 2.7 version, and not my 3.4 version? If not, how do I find out which file is run when I use the python symlink?

Comment: I re-wrote my answer based on the target of the symlink; my homebrew assertion was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably installed that specific Python version using the official Python installer for OS X; see the [*Using Python on a Macintosh* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html). The installer creates the `/usr/local/bin` symlink for you.

If you also, at some point, had 3.4 installed then that installation is still there too. Check for a `/usr/local/bin/python3` command; it'll link to the existing Python 3 binary. Use that instead to run Python 3 code.

If you do have a `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4` command, you *could* re-create the `/usr/local/bin/python` symlink to point there instead, but I'd personally only use the `python3` name for Python 3 scripts.

Last, you could also have used the homebrew tool to install Python; it can manage symlinks for you. However, homebrew installs Python binaries into the `/usr/local/Cellar` tree structure instead.